# Exporting from Layer to Shapefile or feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, layers, export

I am aware that a layer contains style information and a shapefile has vector information, but I am talking about a layer which can be interpreted as shape information.

From my understanding there is some option that lyr file can be some shortcut of other shp and when I upload the lyr it show all the shape information that has in the original one, but now I want to export this lyr so I can use it without harming it, but when I do "right click" then "export data" it's make the shp with field problem like when the field type is a f-code it's make it text and show just the code and not what he present and I want it to be just like the original.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking about is the use case for [Layer Packages](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/saving-layers-and-layer-packages.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_212E5CD02B224118B4CC987C964F5871):

> A layer can be saved with its data as a layer package (.lpk). A layer
>   package includes both the layer properties and the dataset referenced
>   by the layer. With a layer package, you can save and share everything
>   about the layer—its symbolization, labeling, field properties, and the
>   data.

Comment: Sorry man but it's lyr (.lyr) but I think it's not much different. Do you know how to export this kind of lyr or even lpk

Comment: There is an lyr in the lpk. I think you should follow my link and give it a try.

Comment: *Polygeo *  Thanks for your help but I found the tool I've search for it's call "featureclass to feature class"

Comment: I was too focussed on "I want it to be just like the original [layer]".

Comment: I see.. I'll. Try too be more specifc next time. Thank you anyway : )